# Can not parse retrofit rxjava errorBody

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java

this is login error response :

```
 override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
...
...
```

e:response  : error :

```
 [size=86 text={"message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object…]
```

it should be something like this  :  "Wrong username or password ... " 
but it can't cast to desire object . 
I Also tried to cast it to custom object but no success.
Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried running the query using smoehting like Postman to verify that the data is what you expect? Make sure to use the correct user-agent since sometimes responses may vary based on that. Otherwise, show use your class and expected response.